# SQL COUNT Duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to write an SQL statement that lists for me the details of each Patron who attends a hospital as well as how many visits they have made.  Their visits are recorded in the `Registrations` table.  The list is to be sorted by the count of visits.

The following are my tables along with some sample data...

*Patrons*

```
PatronID | FirstName | LastName | eMail
---------|-----------|----------|------
1        | Joe       | Bloggs   | a@a
2        | Trung     | Nguyen   | b@b
```

*Registrations*

```
RegistrationID | PatronID
---------------|---------
1              | 1
2              | 2
3              | 2
4              | 1
5              | 2
```

The following is an example of how I wish for my output to appear...

```
PatronID | FirstName | LastName | eMail | visitsCount
---------|-----------|----------|-------|------------
2        | Trung     | Nguyen   | b@b   | 3
1        | Joe       | Bloggs   | a@a   | 2
```

None of my attempts so far make much sense and the research that I have done is as confusing as it is helpful.  Can someone help me or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: this is one of your homeworks aye? im pretty this is a duplicate where a case was solved by having count

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a *please do my homework for me* site. If you're having difficulties getting started, ask your instructor for help. They're being paid to instruct you, and it appears they have not yet done that job.

Comment: close this @KenWhite

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT Patrons.PatronID,
       FirstName,
       LastName,
       eMail,
       visitsCount
FROM Patrons
INNER JOIN ( SELECT PatronID,
                    COUNT( PatronID ) AS visitsCount
             FROM Registrations
             GROUP BY PatronID
           ) AS visitsCountFinder ON Patrons.PatronID = visitsCountFinder.PatronID
WHERE visitsCount > 1
ORDER BY visitsCount;
```

This works by first drawing up a list of `PatronID` values from `Registrations` and a count of how often that `PatronID` occurs within `Registrations` (which is given the name `visitsCount`).  It then `JOIN`s this list to the `Patrons` table so that each Patron's value of `visitsCount` is placed in the same record as its corresponding record from `Patrons`.

We then `SELECT` the desired fields `WHERE` the count is greater than `1` and sort the resulting record set by their count values.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: I get a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(patronID) VisitsCount'

Comment: Correction posted.

Comment: I am getting the same error. it highlights the vistisCount

Comment: Does it matter that the tables are labeled in all caps? and the columns are camalcase?

Comment: I don't think so.  I've tried correcting the caps in my answer.  If that doesn't work, try putting `[]`'s around each name.  Also are there any spaces or underscores (`_`) in your field names?

Comment: I'll just spin up my copy of access and test this out.  It could take a few minutes.

Comment: i posted a pic of the code you sent, and the error i get in the main post

Comment: I can send you an email with screen shots and the database i have created if it would be easier?

Comment: Not at this stage.

Comment: Sample database created.  One error fixed.  Now hunting the next.

Comment: it was giving me an error on the JOIN, but now it is on visitsCount, on the JOIN line, the last patronID is labeled patronID, I think it should be PatronID

Comment: I've fixed that problem.  One more remains.  I will post corrected code shortly.

Comment: No, I don't have any underscores or spaces in my naming conventions.

Comment: No worries.  Sorry about the runaround.  Please feel free to mark this answer as accepted and to remove the downvote (if you were the one who put it there).  Also, my explanation will be posted shortly.  Finally, may I have your permission to edit your Question into a more preferred format?

Comment: I did not down vote it, i will mark as answered, and yes you can edit it. Thanks Again!

Comment: My edit has been accepted.  Please note how I have phrased the explanation and placed this at the start.  Also note the sample tables (with data) and the desired output (based on the sample data).  These have been formatted as code, which can be done either by selecting the text and clicking on the `{}` button above the text entry area, or by indenting the text by 4 spaces when you are typing it.  It is also good to show, or at least  mention, what research and attempts you have performed.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Answer (score -1):

This will give the list of patrons and their visit counts if they visited more than once:

```
select patrons.patronid, patrons.firstname. patrons.lastname, patrons. email, visits
from
(
    select patronid, count(*) visits
    from registrations
    group by patronid
    having count(*) > 1 
) dups
join patrons on dups.patronid = patrons.patronid
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, but when i ran the code i got a "syntax error in FROM clause."

Comment: Please post the definitions of your 2 tables and indicate what Sql Server you are using.

Comment: I have 3 tables, PATRONS, REGISTRATIONS, and ROOMS. in my PATRONS table, I have PatronID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNum, eMail. in REGISTRATIONS I have RegID, RegDate, PatronID, AdultCnt, ChildCnt, RoomNum, and RegNote. I am using Microsoft Access 2013

Comment: I know I need to use the PatronID in the REGISTRATION table, to find duplicates, once I find them I need to use the PatronID in the PATRONS table to display the FirstName, LastName and eMail. I'm just new to SQL and not sure how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried this Answer?  At first glance it looks like it should do that.

Comment: how do i add a pic to this?